# Remove extra spaces in middle of string split join Python

Tags: python, join, split

I have the following string which forces my Python script to quit:

```
"625             625 QUAIL DR UNIT B"
```

I need to delete the extra spaces in the middle of the string so I am trying to use the following split join script:

```
import arcgisscripting
import logging 
logger = logging.getLogger()

gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)
gp.OverWriteOutput = True

gp.Workspace = "C:\ZP4"
fcs = gp.ListWorkspaces("*","Folder")

for fc in fcs:

    print fc
    rows = gp.UpdateCursor(fc + "//Parcels.shp")
    row = rows.Next()
    while row:
        Name = row.GetValue('SIT_FULL_S').join(s.split())
        print Name
        row.SetValue('SIT_FULL_S', Name)
        rows.updateRow(row)
        row = rows.Next()
    del row
    del rows
```

Comment: Have you saved your file recently and are you sure you're working with the same file?  The code posted doesn't seem to correspond to the error; Line 17 doesn't match the line reproduced in the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your source code and your error do not match, the error states you didn't define the variable `SIT_FULL_S`.

I am guessing that what you want is:

```
Name = ' '.join(row.GetValue('SIT_FULL_S').split())
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, I tried what Martijn suggested and it worked perfectly. Thanks again, and sorry for the confusion over th error statement.

Answer (score 3):

Use the re module...

```
>>> import re
>>> str = 'A   B C'
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', str)
'A B C'
```

Comment: `\s+` means 'one or more' (see [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)), so the more efficient solution can be given, using `\s{2,}` (matching only places where '2 or more' white space characters occured).

Comment: @Tadeck: for the sake future readers, you are probably correct though I'll add that I am betting the difference is tiny if any at all but should be noted by the reader in any case.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should use regular expressions to match all the places where you find two or more spaces and then replace it (each occurence) with a single space.

This can be made using shorter portion of code:

```
re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', your_string)
```

Comment: @Andrew Yes, it is what I meant and I think your answer is the best solution, except it replaces even single spaces with single spaces (which is not needed).

Comment: RE seems to dense for this simple problem.

Comment: @user589983 Why? Do you think is it an overkill?

Comment: @user589983 Let me ask it again: why do you think so?

Comment: @Tadeck: in my experince the runtimes will be nearly identical if not the same though your solution is of course correct. @user589983: this is what regexes were built for. Saying one line of code is overkill needs justification and we have no runtime requirements. @downvoter: Why?

Comment: Because it is not needed... Why would one want to import an extra module when the same effect can be achieved simply without it?

Comment: @user589983 As Andrew said: because this module was built for such purposes. Your proposed solution with `.replace()` method (I am assuming you think it is better than regular expressions) would not get you to achieving the goal (replacing multiple spaces with single ones). Also splitting and gluing the text does not convince me (unless someone proves it is better than regular expressions).

Comment: My solution would have gotten the desired result for the original problem.  I think .split() is the best solution here, I did not downvote you for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear, but I think what you need is:

```
" ".join(row.GetValue('SIT_FULL_S').split())
```

Comment: http://xkcd.com/859/ :). And also must be " ".join(...), else you're removing all the spaces.

Comment: @utdmr: you're right. My reading of the question was that the author wanted to remove all the spaces, but I see now that this is not what he meant.