# Python - Getting Rid of Spaces in String

Tags: python, string

I am retrieving a lot of data in the form

```
6800       MAIN ST
```

How can I format it so that it looks normal (one space between the number and the street name), such as:

```
6800 MAIN ST
```

Comment: `' '.join(mystr.split())`?

Comment: Please try to search before asking a simple question. This one has been asked [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241757/python-django-how-to-remove-extra-white-spaces-tabs-from-a-string) [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130067/remove-extra-spaces-in-middle-of-string-split-join-python) [times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077897/substitute-multiple-whitespace-with-single-whitespace-in-python).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
In [733]: s='6800       MAIN ST'

In [734]: ' '.join(s.split())
Out[734]: '6800 MAIN ST'
```

You can also use `re` as @NPE mentioned, while it's not quite fast even if you get the regex pattern compiled. Benchmark:

```
In [746]: s='asdf             fasd zzzzzz          ddddddd      z'

In [747]: timeit ' '.join(s.split())
1000000 loops, best of 3: 545 ns per loop

In [748]: ptn=re.compile(r"\s+")

In [749]: timeit re.sub(ptn, ' ', s)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.08 us per loop
```

Comment: I would say it's a tie between this and using regex, except it just looks funny to call `join()` on the space and not the array.

Comment: Subjectively, join feels like an operation to be done on a series of things, regardless of whether there's another thing joining them.

Comment: @mgamba It means joining the elements in the iterable with a whitespace. You'll get used to that ;)

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use a regular expression:

```
In [8]: s = "6800       MAIN ST"

In [9]: re.sub(r"\s+", " ", s)
Out[9]: '6800 MAIN ST'
```